# Interpolation with Numpy - non linear method

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

Is there an alternative to the Numpy Interp function where I can in the function inputs I can specify the value to be interpolated, the original data, and also the type of interpolation method?

Currently I am using this to get a single value;

`np.interp(0.74, x_values, y_values)`

But I would like something that can allow me to specify the interpolation method also.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The scipy module has a griddata function which allows you to specify the interpolation method, such as nearest, linear, cubic, etc.

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: the above link is not working. Try this instead: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html